How to implement the Regev's factoring algorithm on Qiskit?
I want to use the Regev algorithm to factorize 77 and demonstrate the principles of the algorithm. However, I am unsure how to construct the specific circuit. Additionally, why does the algorithm start with a discrete Gaussian superposition? And why say that the post-processing of Shor's algorithm can be viewed as a lattice problem?

The post-processing of Shor's algorithm can be viewed as a one-dimensional lattice problem.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
